# How to detect that loaded ORM object has changed?

Tags: orm, kohana, kohana-3

As in title: How to detect that loaded ORM object has changed (current values are different than values in db table)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ORM keeps an array named 'changed' to track the changes in column you can check it like this.

```
public function save()
{
    if (isset($this->changed['name']))
    {
        // set the slug when the name changes -- 'my-post-name'
    $this->slug = url::title($this->name);
    }
}
```

Check this link - http://docs.kohanaphp.com/libraries/orm  => changed

Comment: Thanks, I figured out that if you want to check that ANY of fields changed you can just use $this->_saved; too

Comment: Update for Kohana 3.x

`if($this->changed('name')) {
...
}`

Answer (score 1):

The problem to rely on the changed used by save() method is the comparison used in the set() method is done by !== operator.

So, sometimes if the value is the same, but in one side is string, and in other is integer, ORM will detect it as different.